# Local or global Moran's I minimum neighbor connectivity rules of thumb and justification

Tags: spatial-statistics, geoda

I am trying to run a univariate local Moran's I (in GeoDa) and I'm questioning my spatial weights, trying to do different neighbor counts / distances in increments and evaluate my results.

I was told that all of my locations need a minimum of eight (8) neighbors. Using the range of spatial weights I think is most appropriate (based on familiarity with the dataset and the expectation of what I'm looking for) I have between twelve (12) and twenty (20) records with <8 neighbors out of over fifteen-thousand (15,391) total records. These now-neighbor records are larger polygons near the edges of my map.

I tried understanding 'why' but I can't find much online. Only that ESRI lists it as a requirement and several other places reference it. I'm assuming it has something to do with estimating the local covariance, but I'm not really sure.

I want to know how my analysis will be impacted if it violates this rule. What is the concern with having a small or large number of neighbor counts below eight (8) but above zero (0).

What happens if I continue with these records included and my spatial weights as they are?